# How do I open a Chrome extension in its own window?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, manifest

I installed a Chrome Extension that plays the Pandora client in a web extension (Anesidora), it works fine, but I just can't seem to find a way to open this extension in its own window.

I have to fire up the Chrome browser, click on the extension next to the address bar, and then click on the extension, and as soon as I click away, the music extension disappears, having me to click on the extension and view my music controls again.

Is there a way to update the behavior of the JSON file or `popup.html` or even `backgroud.html` page, so this can be viewed *all by itself* in one page or something?

[image: Pandora music player extension screenshot]

Answer (score 4):

Existing [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325761/934239) by McSod covers a non-invasive method to open a popup of a third-party extension.

If your goal is to permanently modify an extension so that the click opens a separate window instead, and assuming that the popup page does not change throughout the lifetime of the extension, i.e.:

1. It's set by `browser_action.default_popup` in the manifest (assume `"popup.html"`)
2. Nothing in the extension code calls `chrome.browserAction.setPopup` to change it.

Under those conditions, you need to perform 2 actions:

1. Remove the `default_popup` key from the manifest.
2. Modify the background script (or add one, if needed - with `"persistent": false` if that's the only function) to handle the click:

   ```
   chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(tab => {
     chrome.windows.create({
       url: chrome.runtime.getURL("popup.html"),
       type: "popup",
       focused: true,
       /* can also set width/height here, see docs */
     });
   });
   ```

Those are the simplest changes. You can add code that checks for presence of already opened window and re-focusing it instead.

Note that depending on the function of the popup, assumptions in its code (most likely, use of `tabs` API) can break, because it will be the "current tab/window" for itself instead of the page on which the button was clicked.

Comment: Thank You! Xan, for your prompt response. Your solution went into a bit more detail, and I truly appreciate your response as well.  Just what I was looking for.  Thumbs Up!

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood you correctly you just need the URL of the `popup.html`.
Do a right click on the player controls, choose `Inspect` and enter `location.href` in the console. This way you get the URL of the popup that you can use to open the controls in a new browser window.

Comment: This is indeed a good method for a third-part extension you didn't write, though some code may break.

Comment: Thank You! Mr. #McSod - that is very helpful.